# Why is the voltage fluctuating at a divider connected to input of a DC-DC switching regulator?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, voltage-divider

Let me start by saying that I'm a noob at this.

I had the following circuit:

[image]

In place of the DC-DC I was using a RECOM R-78HB12-0.5. [Here's its datasheet.](http://www.recom-power.com/pdf/Innoline/R-78HBxx-0.5_L.pdf) The DC-DC provides 12V, stepped down from a 14S Li-Ion battery in order to power the CA V3. The CA V3 has an input for monitoring battery voltage - Vex - which accepts voltage in the 0-5V range. To provide that voltage, a divider is used - R1,R2. The values I used were 150K, 4.7K.

Once powered on, I measured fluctuating voltage at Vex. It would range between close to the expected value to less than half. The fluctuations didn't seem to exhibit any specific pattern except that if the system was off for some time, it would start close to the expected value.

Can anyone explain what may have been going on? Is there something obvious that I should have done in regards to the DC-DC hook up or could that have been caused by bad connection?

Comment: Is your 52V fluctuating ?

Comment: Not as far as I could tell. It was at a constant 54.6V at the time. It's a big pack as well - 14s4p.

Comment: What is your load?

Comment: Did you add the recommended 3.3uF /100V cap at the input of the DC-DC? Read Datasheet Page 2

Comment: The CA V3 is about 10mA but it's got some extra load hooked to it which should be an additional 35mA, so total 45mA. This has not been measured so these are possibly maximum values and not constant load.

Comment: @ammar.cma no I didn't the circuit was exactly as shown here (except the In Out of the DC-DC are one pin) What does that cap do? Could it be related to the behaviour?

Comment: Besides making sure everything else is working, you need to ensure that your ADC is not being under-fed by the divider. That is, you need a low-enough impedance to make it happy. One way to *ahem* bypass this is to use some filter capacitance at the divider node to even out the gulps of charge the ADC is taking off from there.

Comment: I should probably mention I'm a noob at this. I'm trying to solve a problem and trying learn to do it.

Comment: @Daniel, I measured the voltage fluctuations with a multimeter and that agreed with what I was seeing on the CA V3's display which is driven by its ADC.

Comment: Or could my multimeter be suffering from the same issue?

Comment: If you can see the dips on a multimeter, what I said is probably not the problem. It seems like you have some kind of real circuit problem, not a sampling/measurement problem.

Comment: I think @ammar.cma is on to something, you should definitely add the filter cap and get back to us

Comment: What are the specs for the \$V_{ex}\$ input?

Comment: @jonk, I'm not sure what you mean by that. It takes 0-5V and that eventually get fed to some ADC on the board. I don't know other info about it. However at one point I had R1 disconnected from Vex and measured from R1 to GND and also saw the voltage fluctuating.

Comment: Thanks for that note. So with the divider disconnected from \$V_{ex}\$ you still saw the changes. That removes my question, then.

Comment: I think it basically boils down to - are these observations possible because of the DC-DC or not. If not then I think the most likely explanation is I had a bad solder on the way to Batt+.